# MySQL - Issue with GREATEST() and LEFT JOIN returning NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a problem with a GREATEST() and LEFT JOIN statement that looks like it is related to different versions of MySQL. I have a table that stores a school_id and school_type. There are 4 schools types, and for each school type I have separate table. I have a query that will pull all the schools names from the separate tables, based on school type. So we have the following tables:

tbl_report (stores list of school id's and types)
tbl_grad_school
tbl_lang_school
tbl_high_school

The MySQL statement will pull the name of the school (relative to the school type, plus a few other details from tbl_report. So here is what I have:

```
SELECT
GREATEST(s1.school_name, s2.school_name, s3.school_name) as `school`,
tbl_report.school_id,
tbl_report.school_type,
tbl_report.date,

FROM  tbl_report

LEFT JOIN tbl_grad_school AS s1 ON tbl_report.school_id=s1.id AND tbl_report.school_type=1
LEFT JOIN tbl_lang_school AS s2 ON tbl_report.school_id=s2.id AND tbl_report.school_type=2
LEFT JOIN tbl_high_school AS s3 ON tbl_report.school_id=s3.id AND tbl_report.school_type=3
```

The problem in question is

```
GREATEST(s1.school_name, s2.school_name, s3.school_name) as `school`
```

When using MySQL ver 4.x This works fine, it grabs the name correctly, only choosing the non-Null column. But when using MySQL 5.x, is always shows NULL. If I do a SELECT, pulling out s1.school_name, s2.school_name etc separately, I can see the non-NULL columns fine, but using GREATEST doesn't work.

Any ideas what's happened? This is a very important part of MySQL code that I use frequently throughout my programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`greatest()` seems like an odd choice here.  In any case, since version 5.0 or so, it returns `NULL` if *any* of the values are `NULL`.

Perhaps this is what you really want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(s1.school_name, s2.school_name, s3.school_name) as `school`,
```

This returns the first non-NULL value.